# I have a parent view and in a partial view with a table when loading the parent view I want to hide the partial as long as the table has no data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a parent view and in a partial view with a table when loading the parent view I want to hide the partial as long as the table has no data

```cs
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                Guayaquil_Turismo.Models.Modelo_Estado_de_Cuenta declaracion = new Models.Modelo_Estado_de_Cuenta();

                Guayaquil_Turismo.Models.Valores_a_Pagar Valor_Paga = new Models.Valores_a_Pagar();

                List<PernoctaDeclaraciones> ModelDeclaraciones = new List<PernoctaDeclaraciones>();

                using (var db = new tecserne_guayaquil_desaContext())
                {
                    System.Security.Claims.Claim claim_Establecimiento = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GroupSid).FirstOrDefault();
                    Valor_Paga = db.Valores_a_Pagar.Where(x => x.IdEstablecimiento == int.Parse(claim_Establecimiento.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
                    ModelDeclaraciones = db.PernoctaDeclaraciones.Where(x => x.IdEstablecimiento == int.Parse(claim_Establecimiento.Value) && x.EstadoPago == "P").OrderByDescending(x => x.MesDeclaracion).ToList();
                    foreach (PernoctaDeclaraciones item in ModelDeclaraciones)
                    {
                        item.PernoctaMultas.Add(db.PernoctaMultas.Where(x => x.IdDeclaracion == item.IdDeclaracion).FirstOrDefault());
                        foreach (PernoctaIntereses item2 in db.PernoctaIntereses.Where(x => x.IdDeclaracion == item.IdDeclaracion).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.MesInteres))
                        {
                            item.PernoctaIntereses.Add(item2);
                        }
                    }
                    declaracion.Declaraciones = ModelDeclaraciones;
                    declaracion.ValorPaga = Valor_Paga;
                    return View(declaracion);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Estado_Fecha(string fecha_)
        {
            List<PernoctaDeclaraciones> obj_fechas = new List<PernoctaDeclaraciones>();
            using (var db = new tecserne_guayaquil_desaContext())
            {
                string[] fechas = fecha_.Split("-");
                fechas[0].ToString();
                fechas[1].ToString();
                DateTime Fechas1 = DateTime.Parse(fechas[0].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
                DateTime Fechas2 = DateTime.Parse(fechas[1].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fecha_))
                {

                    obj_fechas = db.PernoctaDeclaraciones.Where(x => x.FechaDeclaracion >= Fechas1 & x.FechaDeclaracion <= Fechas2).ToList();
                }
            }
            return View(obj_fechas);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type of `table` property in view model is List/Array , you can try

```
@if (Model.table!= null && Model.table.Count != 0)
{
    <partial name="_name" />
}
```

If the type of `table` property in view model is `IEnumerable` , you can try :

```
@if (Model.table!= null && Model.table.Count() != 0)
{
    <partial name="_name" />
}
```